# How does a method find the instance variables of its object at runtime

Tags: java, object, jvm

When an object is created and one of its public methods is called it can use local attribute. Where are they stored? I mean, in a language like C, it's all clear: variables to be used have to be passed to functions as parameters (or have to be global).

What does it happen in Java (and maybe other OO languages)? How can be instance's attributes used by local methods?

In a nutshell: when we say `this.variable`, how can a method find its own variable? Is "this" pointer passed implicitly as function parameter?

Comment: Primitives stored on the *stack*, objects and instances are in the *heap*. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun it's not exactly what I'm asking. When you say this.variable how can a method find it's own variable? Is "this" pointer passed implicitly as function parameter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by local attributes? Depending on how the methods are defined, you can certainly pass variables from the current scope as parameters.

Comment: @HAL9000 The proper term is instance variable or field.  These are stored on the heap because they are a part of the instance of the class, which is an object and objects are stored on the heap.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I fixed it, thanks. Ok I understand that this points to the heap, but, reasoning in assembly, how can a method know the current "this" pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: each instance method is a function which declares one more argument than what is explicitly declared. The first argument is always the implicit `this` reference (pointer). This is only thinly disguised by Java's syntax:

```
firstArg.method(secondArg, thirdArg)
```

is just another way of writing

```
method(firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg)
```

And note the special characteristic of the first argument: it is the only one upon whose type the *dynamic dispatch* of methods takes place.

Comment: Ok you exactly understood what I was asking, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Primitives            → Stack
References to Objects → Stack
Objects               → Heap
Strings               → heap
String Literals       → String Pool (part of heap)
```

Comment: So when you call object.method() is "this" pointer passed as implicit parameter to method in order to retrieve object's variables from heap?

Comment: `this` points to the instance of the `Object` and objects are stored on the heap.

Comment: @TheLostMind I try to explain better. A method is coded ONCE. When you call a method he can access the attributes of instance, through "this" reference. How can the method (which is coded ONCE) know its current "this" reference?

Comment: @HAL9000 - look.. A method which is coded once is placed in memory. Now, you call a method "through" an object. So, the method which is called already has a reference to the object on which it is being called. this is used to internally represent the current object.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the local variables type.  If the variable is an object it will be stored on the Heap, however if it is a primitive it will be stored on the stack.

```
public class Storage{

   //as fields or instance variables on the object they are also stored on heap
   public int y;  
   public MyObject obj2 = new MyObject();

   public static void main(String[] args){
       Storage storage = new Storage(); //This is an object, it is stored on the heap
   }

   public void do(){
      int x = 1; //stored on stack;
      MyObject obj = new MyObject(); //stored on heap  
   }

}

class MyObject{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that one shouldn't forget about [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) as well. As it's said in docs,

> Escape analysis is a technique by which the Java Hotspot Server
>   Compiler can analyze the scope of a new object's uses and decide
>   whether to allocate it on the Java heap.

([src](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis))

*Except, well, that as for now it's not that new*